# Apache Kafka : Can be used to push data to IoT devices?

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices

I have some **IoT devices** which need to be updated sometimes, based on configuration done in web or mobile clients. **So I need to give capability to be updated based on a configuration.**

I have the following architecture when **Clients** communicates over HTTPS to an **API Gateway**. This Gateway is responsible to fetch data from several **micro-services** that interact with **Kafka** and some databases.

In this context, it is a good idea to create a Kafka consumer in IoT devices that will consumes messages from a Kafka Configuration Topic ?

Based on each new message received on this topic, the IoT device will be responsible to apply the change on the configuration.

Any advise ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Usually, IoT devices have strong CPU/RAM and/or battery restrictions. The most widely used solution for messaging over IoT is MQTT and https://mosquitto.org/ the currently most widespread MQTT broker, so I would try to use https://mosquitto.org/ on the IoT devices and link it with Kafka through a "Confluent MQTT Proxy", you have more information at https://www.confluent.io/confluent-mqtt-proxy/
It is also not difficult to create your own "MQTT proxy" in python (or the language you prefer)

Answer (score 0):

Kafka does not push. Consumers poll.

You can embed Kafka consumers in IoT devices, yes (assuming you are able to deploy such apps into them), however, MQTT is often documented as more used in those environments, and you could route Kafka events to an MQTT broker through various methods.

Comment: the kafka protocol is too heavyweight and chatty to scale to a very high number of devices - I woult not feel comfortable with a million consumers, for example.

Comment: @rad OP didn't state amount of devices. I'd assume not each device is a unique consumer group

Comment: Imagine that IoT devices are some devices with a Linux system embeeded. Is it better to produce Kafka message by emebedding a Kafka producer or to use MQTT ?

Comment: @wawa based on blogs and presentations only, then MQTT, which can then be forwarded to Kafka